# How to enable GCC global constructors when linking a mingw library with Microsoft linker

Tags: mingw, cross-compiling, msvcrt

I have a static library that is cross-compiled gcc/mingw to be linked into a Windows DLL.

This library contains a function that is marked with `__attribute__(constructor)` .

I have found a description of how this mechanism works in mingw here: [How does GCC implement __attribute__((constructor)) on MinGW?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60971878/how-does-gcc-implement-attribute-constructor-on-mingw)

Unfortunately, this mechanism relies on the binary being linked with the mingw linker. Is there a way to run that code when the final DLL is linked with the Microsoft MSVC linker?

So, for example, is there a way to combine the mingw-generated `.ctor` sections into the one of the `.CRT$XCU` sections used by the Microsoft CRT?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/crt-initialization?view=msvc-170

Simply renaming the section with `objcopy` before linking does not seem to work.

Comment: Why don't you compile and link everything with the same compiler?

Comment: Fair question: the (inner) static library is third-party code, uses GCC-only constructs, relies on libgcc and libmingw and thus cannot easily be ported to MSVC. The outer library is in-house and directly written in a retargetable manner with native build on Windows and Linux. Switching the outer library to cross-compilation would make everybody's life more complicated.

Comment: GCC on Windows is also 'native'.

Comment: Yes, but I would still prefer using MSVC for the outer build because that is what is generally available on our build machines.

Comment: Mixing compilers and linkers in a single project is just a bad idea.
Have you tried building your entire project with MinGW-w64?
Or if you really prefer MSVC, have you tried calling the constructor from `main`/`WinMain` yourself at startup?

Comment: Calling the constructor is the workaround that I am using at the moment, and it works fine (but this is only feasible as long as their are few such constructors, which is the case at the moment). Looks like there is no good "clean" solution for this at the moment.